# Catch Exception at Transaction Commit in Seam

Tags: java, jpa, seam

Everytime the user clicks the delete button to delete something, I call

```
em.remove(entity)
```

In case there are still referential constrains to this entity, I see an PersistenceException being thrown, and I can catch it to notice the user.

However, that is only for relationship that I can see in code. For example:

```
A has an OneToMany relationship to B
```

In a few special cases, the relationship is not reflected in code. For example:

```
Table A has a foreign key to Table B. But in code, there is no XtoX relationship between them
```

In these cases, I can't catch the PersistenceException mentioned above, which make the exception appears very ugly on the screen.

What I think is the exception appears at transaction commit time.

Is there anyway catch it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JPA, `em.flush()` method can used to catch the exception. After this operation is done, you will get the exception if you have the problem.

For example:

```
public void insert(Group group) {
    try {
        em.persist(group);
        em.flush();
    } catch (PersistenceException pe) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. How come I missed it

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using Seam's (2.x) exception handling facilities that let you handle uncaught exceptions - e.g. print error message and/or re-direct to an error page - rather than possibly coupling your persistence related logic for this purpose.  This could still give you more error handling implementation approaches even if you'd still like to flush the persistence context.  See [exception handling in the Seam documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.2.2.Final/reference/en-US/html/events.html#d0e5644).  Depending on your application's needs, the Seam ExceptionHandler class can be extended for further customization.  See [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5458247/1388064).