# How do I debug Facelets page rendering issues?

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, seam, facelets

I am using JBoss 7.1, Seam 2.2.2.

When rendering a page I am getting the Facelets debug page with a NullPointerException without any line number indicating where on the page it is occurring.  Are there some standard tricks to debug such issues?  I can't see any way to put in log statements, etc in this case.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried looking at your JBoss server.log?

Comment: What I get in the server log is only the stack trace after the crash.  The stack does not have any of my code called in it so I can't set breakpoints.  My question is how do I narrow down where in the page render the null pointer occurred.

Answer (score 0):

This post may be helpful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5458247/498531. Basically it lets you override a built-in Seam component to print a stacktrace of any exception thrown. It helped me once that I inadvertently had two `toString()` methods calling each other, and all I was just getting from the logs was a StackOverflowError, with no reference to any line of my code.